# Make a stream read() blocking

Tags: python, fcntl

What's the inverse of this?

```
fcntl.fcntl(MyStream.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

I've tried

```
fcntl.fcntl(MyStream.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_BLOCK)
```

but it results in a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'O_BLOCK'`.

To give a little background, I'm piping data in chunks into STDIN of a `popen`'ed process. If there is data waiting in STDOUT, I need to read it straight away and pass it back to the client (hence switching to non-blocking). However, when I've finished piping data in, I then need to block until I get an EOF on STDOUT.

If there's a better way to do this (ideally cross-platform?) then I'm all ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current flag and turn off O_NONBLOCK bit:

```
flag = fcntl.fcntl(MyStream.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(MyStream.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flag & ~os.O_NONBLOCK)
```